# Using Pycharm debug django meet error

Tags: python, mysql, django, pycharm

I tried to debug my django project using pycharm, but failed with errors about connecting to mysql database with "Error loading MySQLdb module". I actually have meet this problem when I was connecting django with mysql at first and solved it by adding a line of 
"export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/" in bash_profile because in my Mac mysql is stalled in this path. I tried add this variable to Pycharm preference's Python console and Django console but it still doesn't work.
I think this might because Pycharm has a built in environment variable settings but how can I fix this problem?
Thanks for helping!

Btw I'm using Macbook, Python3.5, Django1.10, MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Debugging in PyCharm , you should first set your virtual environment in **Edit Configuration** :

1. Select **Run** from the toolbar menu.
2. Click **Edit Configuration**.
3. In new Dialog box select your project's virtual environment next to **Python interpreter** .
4. After that debug your project.(It should work)

If you don't find your virtual environment in the options in 3rd step, try to add your virtual environment in PyCharm like this:

1. Select **File** from toolbar menu.
2. Select **settings** option from the dropdown.
3. In new dialog select **Project: MyProject> Python Interpreter** option              from left side menu.
4. From the upper right side select the "add"**("+")** sign and locate your virtual environment directory. You will see that sign that i marked below on image:
   [image]

And after that repeat the first process of configuration editing.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it by adding that DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in Edit Configuration! Perfect answer!

Comment: Cheers ! @StopIteration404